# Python - Doing absolute imports from a subfolder

Tags: python, python-import

Basically I'm asking the same question as this guy: [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

But no one gave him a correct answer. Given that you are inside a subfolder and you want to go up a directory and then into ANOTHER subfolder, doing what they suggested does not work (as the OP pointed out in his comments to their answers).

I know that you can do this by using sys.path, but I would prefer a cleaner method.

Example:

```
App
__init__.py
Package_A
--__init__.py
--Module_A.py
Package_B
--__init__.py
--Module_B.py
```

How would I import Module_A into Module_B?

Comment: By "Module_A" do you mean "Package_A"?  A package contains an "__init__.py and, possibly, additional Modules.  Can you rewrite your "Module_A"'s and "Module_B"'s to be "Package_A" and "Package_B" so your question is more clear?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
main.py
setup.py
app/ ->
    __init__.py
    package_a/ ->
       __init__.py
       module_a.py
    package_b/ ->
       __init__.py
       module_b.py
```

1. You run `python main.py`.
2. `main.py` does: `import app.package_a.module_a`
3. `module_a.py` does `import app.package_b.module_b`

Alternatively 2 or 3 could use: `from app.package_a import module_a`

That will work as long as you have `app` in your PYTHONPATH. `main.py` could be anywhere then.

So you write a `setup.py` to copy (install) the whole app package and subpackages to the target system's python folders, and `main.py` to target system's script folders.

Comment: The main thing is to add the appropriate `__init__.py` files to each directory and to include `app` in your import statement. If you do that, adding the line `import app.package_a.module_a` to `module_b.py` should do the appropriate import. Basically, step 3 is what you want, the rest is extraneous unless you're planning on distributing the package.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm [reading](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) [correctly](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html), in Python 2.5 or higher:

```
from ..Module_B import Module_B
```

I thought I was well-versed in Python but I had no idea that was possible in version 2.5.

Comment: That's correct. It's a bit ugly though, and absolute imports are generally the best thing except in special circumstances.

Comment: THis doesn't work I get "attempted relative import in non-package"

Comment: The statement is assumed to be inside Module_A.py (and, post-edit, should be from ..Package_B.) relative imports are based on the package path of the module you are inside, not directories; you can't use them from a top-level script or simple module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are then importing Module_B in to App, you would

Module_B.py:
    import ModuleA

App.py (which also imports ModuleA which is now by default in your Pythonpath)

```
import Module_B.Module_B
```

Another alternative, is to update __init__.py (the one in Module_A/App folder) to:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.extend('%s../' % os.getcwd())
import ModuleA
```

Another alternative, is to add your folder to the PYTHONPATH environment var.

Comment: Modifying `sys.path` at runtime is nearly always wrong. It's fragile and indicates a badly-structured package.